# Cloudformation Error - Resource of type 'AWS::ApiGateway::Model' with identifier 'Empty' already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an APIGateway using Cloudformation. When attempting to create via the AWS CF Console I am recieving this error:
[image]

The EmptyModel resource is a AWS::ApiGateway::Model object that looks like this:

```
    EmptyModel:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Model"
    Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
        Name: "Empty"
        Description: "This is a default empty schema model"
        Schema: |
            {
              "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
              "title" : "Empty Schema",
              "type" : "object"
            }
        ContentType: "application/json"
```

I am referencing this model on every one of my AWS::ApiGateway::Method objects in the CF Template like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I used Former2 to reverse engineer my current api and get some of this template for the new api I am creating. So I am wondering if there is just something weird in this? Any help is hella appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to identify this issue finally through much trial and error. Apparently Models are shared between all of the APIs in your account (or maybe just region)

So the error was indicating that there was already a model called "Empty" and that is because there was one, in a different API. I changed the name to "EmptyModel" and it worked great!

Comment: Worked like a charm! One thing surprising is, the models are named "Empty" rather than "EmptyModel" after the creation!

Answer (score 0):

If you used former2 to create your template from existing resources, you **can't just deploy** the template obtained, as you will get the errors you are getting.

Instead you have to modify the template and [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) your resources to CloudFormation. Or easier, you have to delete existing resources, and then re-create them using CloudFormation.

Comment: I am getting this error even when deploying to a new AWS account with no resources. Tried cli command `aws apigateway get-models` but it requires the `rest-api-id` argument, which isn't there as this is the first API!